# Encrypting WIM files

Tags: images, deployment, dism, winpe, wim

We use WIM files to deploy images on workstations (we use DISM on WinPE).

Is there a way to encrypt the WIM file while it sits on the flash drive, and decrypt it upon use?

We haven't found this option on the DISM tool, and we try to avoid copying/extracting the file elsewhere, to avoid the time it takes.

Thank you in advance,
Yaron.

Comment: DISM itself doesn't support it and it's unclear what your requirement would be. If it's a transparent encryption someone could still just take the USB, plug it in and copy it.

Comment: Thanks Seth,
The requirement is indeed transparent encryption, but it can be called with a password, for example.
like: 
DismOrAnotherTool /Apply-Image /... /password:MyPassword

Comment: Put the WIM on a BitLocker to Go volume?

Comment: We thought about it - but we weren't sure we'll be able to boot from it then

Comment: BitLocker to go would probably the wrong approach as it usually encrypts the whole drive but you could setup a second partition with the WIM, unlock it in your PE environment and use that. At least [it seems possible](https://4sysops.com/archives/unlock-bitlocker-under-windows-pe/) to use BitLocker in a PE environment.

Comment: Ah, that actually sounds like a very good idea.
Will try that - and get back here to update. Thanks, Seth!